# Remove the previous value and update the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Having problem with removing the previous value from the array and updating with the remaining data.

For example, in the code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y97rbvo9/4/) I have four values in the array: BMW, Nissan, Volvo and Saab.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" , "Nissan"];
shuffle(cars);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
```

So, once I "Press a button" it shows "BMW" or any other value, next time reloading should only randomize within the rest of the value i.e. Nissan, Volvo and Saab.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", **"BMW"** , "Nissan"];
```

until all ends and it shows "No more value to be shown"

Comment: Refreshing (reloading) the page will reset all the javascript (including the array) to default values (all four in this case).  If you included a button the user could click, then the information could be processed out on click event.

Comment: you need to persist the ones used in localStorage to work between reloads.

Comment: @rfornal agree I think button would be better. But how do I remove and update once the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  return array.splice(Math.random() * array.length, 1).pop();
}

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW" , "Nissan"];
var car = shuffle(cars);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car;
```

#### Update

Also note that JSFiddle is reloading the whole JS each time, ie. reloading the initialization of `cars` each time, so it's refreshing it with all four initial values each time you run it.

Comment: Right, sorry, I just updated my answer :) I actually didn't read your code closely because it was complex and long, I just assumed you knew it wasn't doing what it was meant to even when you weren't re-initializing the `cars` array each time :)

Comment: Look at your JS console, those functions aren't automatically visible from the HTML. You need to attach them to `window` like so: hhttp://jsfiddle.net/y97rbvo9/5/

Comment: Is there a way to show 2 array element in the list, instead of 1 at a time?

Comment: Yes, assuming you want them both randomly, just take the same code that's there and call it twice, or even just call `shuffle(cars)` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on a button click event ...

```
function removeCard() {
    var index = 0;
    cars.splice(index, 1);
    if (cars.length>0) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "none left";
    }
}
```

... click event ...

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", removeCar());
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nissan"];
shuffle(cars);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var index = 0;
    cars.splice(index, 1);
    if (cars.length>0) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "none left";
    }
});
```

A bit leaner and cleaner.  **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y97rbvo9/6/)**